# How to get all the id from JSTREE

Tags: jstree

I am trying to collect every node id from JSTREE so that I can get the MAX ID.

I think it's straightfowrad.... Any reply is appreciated Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = [];
$('.jstree-leaf').each(function(){
  ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```